# PHP SMTP not working with GMAIL

Tags: smtp, gmail

Anyone can help me see which part I have wrong...since I ask my hosting provider also no one wanna give help on this...I already spent whole day with this SMTP and tried many different codes from the internet but still cant send out a single simple email...anyone plss...

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'maxsmtp88@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'emailpasswordhere';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'maxsmtp88@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Max';
$mail->addAddress('maxsmtp88@gmail.com', 'Max');     // Add a recipient  
$mail->addReplyTo('maxsmtp88@gmail.com', 'Max');
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

I really don't understand this SMTP is helping the hosting provider to prevent bad reputation on spamming how come THEY do not want to help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port number to 587 and in your gmail account settings, allow access for less secure apps.